# Configure the deployment directory in firebase functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have an existing nodejs application built on typescript.

The existing nodejs application structure is as follows

```
ROOT
 - dist
 - src
  - *.ts
 - test
 - package.json
 - gulpfile.json
 - .env
```

All the compilation goes under dist and the application works fine.

I am already using firebase functions for many tasks and would want to use the same for this application as well.

Now I am trying to integrate firebase functions inside this project directly. The revised structure is

```
ROOT
 - dist
 - src
  - *.ts
  - workers <firebase functions>
    - index.ts
 - test
 - package.json
 - gulpfile.json
 - .env
 - firebase.json
 - .firebaserc
```

To ensure that firebase looks at proper folder, I have configured the folder in firebase.json to point to root directory

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "."
  }
}
```

Apart from the I have made necessary changes in package.json

```
{
  ...
  "main": "dist/workers/index.js",
  "engines": {
        "node": "10"
  },
  ...
```

These configurations ensure that I am able to run the functions on cloud shell

```
firebase functions:shell --debug
```

The issue is on deploying the function.

```
firebase deploy --only functions --debug
```

The firebase deployment is looking to deploy my entire directory causing 400 error. The debug log clearly shows the package size is more than 300 MB, essentially packaging all unnecessary files.

How can I ensure that firebase deployment deploys only the required folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase CLI will unconditionally deploy everything under what you designate as "source", minus node_modules, which will be rebuilt by Cloud Functions using `npm install` on the service side.  There is no way to add or omit files from this location.

By default, a Firebase CLI initialized project creates a folder called "functions", and uses that as the root of all your functions-related code and config, including package.json and all source and transpiled code.  This is generally how a project is intended to be organized.

Given this requirement, you should probably reconsider adding functions to an existing project, and keeping the functions code in its own project.  There are ways to share code between projects, if that's what you need to do, which is a different topic to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Yes I have a separate functions project and that is working fine. The reason for attempting to use firebase functions under my core repo was to see if I could leverage on the already existing models and services. I think the only way out is to separate the services or restructure the current code similar to firebase structure. Is there any other alternative suggestions ?

Comment: I don't have anything specific.  Use your best judgement.